# Serializing an object to file with encryption in a UWP app

Tags: c#, encryption, serialization, uwp

Ok so I have this method for serializing my player object to an XML file,
I've been trying to find a way to encrypt the data before writing the object to the file.
there are many posts here and over the internet concerning this topic and I tried to combine all the data so it works on my app and ended up with this:

```
    public static async Task SaveAsync<T>(Player player)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccess = null;
        string strAlgName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc;
        UInt32 keyLength = 32;
        CryptographicKey key;
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);
        IBuffer keyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(keyLength);
        key = objAlg.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        IBuffer iv = null;
        if (strAlgName.Contains("CBC"))
        {
            iv = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(objAlg.BlockLength);
        }
        StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Data.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        sessionRandomAccess = await sessionFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        IBuffer buffEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, ReadFully(sessionRandomAccess.AsStream()).AsBuffer(), iv);
        DataContractSerializer sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Player), new Type[] { typeof(T) });
        Stream stream = buffEncrypt.AsStream();
        sessionSerializer.WriteObject(stream, player);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }
```

And the method to convert the stream to bytes array:

```
    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Now it all works well until the WriteObject method called then I'll get this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to expand length of this stream beyond
>   its capacity.

Anyone have any Idea how to solve this and why it actually occurs?
Thanks

Update:
I thought I might add the Decryption method that Worked for me as an addition to the great Answer that included the encryption part by Jay Zuo - MSFT.

so here it is:

```
    public static async Task<Player> LoadAsync<T>()
    {
        try
        {

                StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Data.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                if (sessionFile == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                IBuffer buffEncrypt = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(sessionFile);
                String strAlgName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7;
                CryptographicKey key;              // Symmetric key
                // Open a symmetric algorithm provider for the specified algorithm.
                SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);
                key = objAlg.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
                IBuffer buffMsg=CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, buffEncrypt, iv);
                DataContractSerializer sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Player));
                return (Player)sessionSerializer.ReadObject(buffMsg.AsStream());
            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Note two things the iv IBuffer and the keyMaterial where stored and loaded from the database as  Jay Zuo - MSFT suggested.
Hope this helps some one:)

Comment: It is as the error message stated, there's not enough space in the stream to contain the serialized object. You instantiated stream with the buffer containing the encrypted data; I'm not 100% sure, but it would seem the stream created so would be fixed in size according to the IBuffer. Serialization would need more space than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To encrypt a serialized object, we can get the [IBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241656) that represents the serialized object first.

```
IBuffer buffMsg;

DataContractSerializer sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Player));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    sessionSerializer.WriteObject(stream, player);

    buffMsg = stream.ToArray().AsBuffer();
}
```

Then we can encrypt the buffer like following:

```
IBuffer iv;                        // Initialization vector
CryptographicKey key;              // Symmetric key
UInt32 keyLength = 32;             // Length of the key, in bytes
String strAlgName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc;

// Initialize the initialization vector.
iv = null;

// Open a symmetric algorithm provider for the specified algorithm.
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);

// Determine whether the message length is a multiple of the block length.
// This is not necessary for PKCS #7 algorithms which automatically pad the
// message to an appropriate length.
if (!strAlgName.Contains("PKCS7"))
{
    if ((buffMsg.Length % objAlg.BlockLength) != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Message buffer length must be multiple of block length.");
    }
}

// Create a symmetric key.
IBuffer keyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(keyLength);
key = objAlg.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);

// CBC algorithms require an initialization vector. Here, a random
// number is used for the vector.
if (strAlgName.Contains("CBC"))
{
    iv = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(objAlg.BlockLength);
}

// Encrypt the data and return.
IBuffer buffEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buffMsg, iv);
```

Once we have the encrypted buffer, we can write it into a file:

```
StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Data.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(sessionFile, buffEncrypt);
```

Please note that [SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.aescbc) is a [no padding algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.algorithmname). While using this algorithm, the message buffer length that we want to encrypt must be multiple of block length. As the buffer length of the serialized object is mutable, I'd suggest using a PKCS #7 algorithm such as [SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.aescbcpkcs7) instead of `SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc`. And for decryption, you may also need to store **Symmetric key** and  **Initialization vector**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , while SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc  didn't work and kept throwing the double size needed exception,I did as you sugested and used PKCS #7 instead and it worked perfectly, i have a small question left I'm willing to store the Symmetric key and Initialization vector in my Azure Sql databse through the web app service that I created, have you any suggestions about what data type would be best to store them and if there is a conversion needed how should I go about this?

Comment: @FadiBanna In the sample, Initialization vector is a `Buffer` and Symmetric key is also created from `keyMaterial` which is also a `Buffer`. And Azure SQL Database supports [binary or varbinary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx). So we can use `ToArray` method like `keyMaterial.ToArray();` to get the `byte[]` and then store them in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: @FadiBanna  Another way would be storing them as string. We can use some methods such as [CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.encodetobase64string.aspx) to convert the buffers to base64 strings and then store the string in  Azure SQL Database. When decryption, we can retrieve the strings and use [DecodeFromBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.decodefrombase64string.aspx) to get the buffers again.

Comment: @FadiBanna You can choose either of them according to your scenario. Hope this helps. ;-)